# How to reproduce this template?

Tags: templates

I would like to use this type of example below for my work on Latex. I am new to using this program.

Using inputs from other members of the community I have managed to do part of the question above. However, I fail to make functions lettrine or automatic numbering. Can you help with these two issues?

[image]

This is my current MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\newcommand{\mipbox}[2]{\indent\hspace{2mm}\parbox{#1} {\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{#2}}}
\setlist{leftmargin=3.9mm}

\newcommand{\mylist}{\tikz[overlay]\draw[ ultra thick,blueline](-.2,-.2)--(-.2,.4) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.3,.15); $\;$}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\mylist]}

\newcommand{\mylists}{\tikz[overlay]\draw[ ultra thick,blueline](-.2,-.2)--(-.2,.4) [path fading=east](-.2,.15)--(.5,.15); $\;$}
\newcommand{\myitems}{\item[\mylists]}
\newcommand{\ita}{\textit}


\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{blueline}{HTML}{2F74D0}
\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\arrayrulecolor{blueline}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l  | X  }

    \multicolumn{2}{>{\mdseries}p{\textwidth}}{\ita{First row of the table - some long text in bold font with background color. This needs to wrap properly. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc venenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec}.}\\ \hline
   2&\vspace{1mm}\hspace{5mm}\textcolor{blueline}{\textbf{Respuestas}}\\
 22& \begin{itemize}  \parbox{10cm}{
    \myitem a)  kkk enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec.
    \myitem b) enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec. }\mipbox{1cm}{optiM2.png}
    \myitem c) hshsg gsfdg  hshsgddc h hgddh  sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante la
    \begin{itemize}[topsep=-5pt,leftmargin=14.5mm,itemsep=0.8pt,labelsep=.5cm]
    \myitems i) kshdg
    \myitems ii) jsjshdfgf
    \end{itemize}
    \myitem  sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante la  sed pellentesque ante laoreet nec enenatis nunc dui, sed pellentesque ante la
    \end{itemize} \\ \hline \hline    
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on, even if it does not do all the things that your template shows.

Comment: The down votes seem unfair for someone new to our forum.  Also, somewhere before someone asked a very similar question.  So far though my searches are not turning up the possible duplicate.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, it is necessary to read some introductory material.

Comment: As it stands I'm not sure what is wanted: your code example does look like the image. Can you focus in on a specific problematic point?